# dockerized java application access a monetdb database which has been deploied on a jupyterhub via docker

Tags: java, docker, monetdb, jupyterhub

There is a monetdb docker deployed on the jupyterhub, I'm developing a Java application which will use the data from the database on the jupyterhub.

Is there a way to write in the code to make the access to the database via internet, so that users can get and write records in runtime?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific code for that. You can used the JDBC/ODBC  libraries to access a remote database.